# Adding new device to tester in TestFlight

Tags: iphone, testflight

Our tester have new device with same email address. They want to me add this new device to TestFlight.
So tester have two devices anymore. Tester accept my new invitation by new device but i still see only one and old device (UDID) in TestFlight>Testers section.
How can i solve this? How can i add this new device?
I deleted tester from TestFlight and add him again but still no result.
Any help please.

Comment: You can't do this. The tester has to add the device by signing in on the new device.

Comment: @phix23 But he can do this with same e-mail address? So i sent this email adress to invitation, he opened with new device and accepted it. I see he accepted it in TestFlight but i still see only old device.

Comment: @phix23 Ok i got it what you mean. I solved this. Thanks, if you will post it with details i can accept it as an answer. So it ll help to other people.